# Get Client URL from WCF

Tags: wcf

I have a problem here in WCF.

I have my WCF service which is exposed in web and multiple sites are consuming the same WCF.

I wanted to identify URL's (not the IP's) of these sites with in the service itself.

Can some body share me your thoughts....

Thanks,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

You can't get such information unless you send it as part of request (datacontract) into your service. The service application has no information about exposed URLs of client applications.